# function to produce list of elements by group (R)

Tags: r, list, data.table

I have a transient amnesia. I recall there's an R function that allows to get list of elements in a group after aggregating.
To be clearer, from here:

```
DT<-data.table(x=rep(c("cool","uncool"),each=3),group=c(1,1,2,2,3,3))
```

That gives:

```
    x    group
   cool     1
   cool     1
   cool     2
 uncool     2
 uncool     3
 uncool     3
```

I would like to end up with:

```
 x      group
cool    1,1,2
uncool  2,3,3
```

I used that function in the past, but can't remember now. Anyone can help?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

Using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(group ~ x, DT, toString)
#       x   group
#1   cool 1, 1, 2
#2 uncool 2, 3, 3
```

or

```
aggregate(group ~ x, DT, paste0, collapse = ",")
#       x group
#1   cool 1,1,2
#2 uncool 2,3,3
```

### Option 2

The `data.table` way

```
DT[, .(group = toString(group)), by = x]
#    x       group
#1:   cool 1, 1, 2
#2: uncool 2, 3, 3
```

or

```
DT[, .(group = paste0(group, collapse = ",")), by = x]
#        x group
#1:   cool 1,1,2
#2: uncool 2,3,3
```

Comment: It works, thanks! But it wasn't the one I was using. I think that function included square brackets, something like "[".

Comment: @LaMachineInfernale I've added a `data.table` solution, please take a look; perhaps this was what you were after?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
DT %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(group = toString(group))
```